# KVM with DDM and 2 x DisplayPort

Tags: kvm-switch

I'm currently looking for a KVM that supports two monitors with a resolution of   2560 × 1440 and has DDM or at least Semi-DDM for input devices.

DVI ist not an option, even if Dual-Layer is supported, as one of the connected devices will be a laptop with only USB-C and that cannot reasonably converted into dual-layer DVI. MST support on the output side (input needs to be two seperate displayport cables, as one of the devices does not have MST) would be nice for cleaner cable management, however two seperate DisplayPorts would also work.

DDM is mandatory though, as emulation does not work for me (gaming mouse & keyboard) and simple pass-through is too slow (full enumeration needed every time I switch).

Please do not suggest software solutions. I know they exist (even though there's only one or two that do KVM and not only KM), but they need always need the master device to be running, which is not something I'm willing to do.

Comment: So far I have found the Aten CS1942DP that states it has "Mouse & Keyboard emulation / bypass" but does not specify what exactly "bypass" means. Does anyone know if that is supposed to be DDM or just simple pass-through? It also states it is "compatible with most gaming HDI" (or something along those lines) but Aten does not provide a list with compatible (tested) HDI.

Comment: Aten is out, support told me it's not (Semi-)DDM but only pass-through and does not work with any keyboard that uses n-key rollover even with emulation disabled.

Comment: Startech seems close but I think the use of the word "hub" and not "ddm" implies that it's not DDM.  https://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/2-port-dual-dp-kvm-switch~SV231DPDDUA2

Comment: @ragerdl Can confirm - I emailed startech about that KVM-switch a while ago and they told me it is indeed not DDM.

Answer (score 3):

The only KVM's with DisplayPorts and DDM that I've found are from ConnectPro. They also support two monitors, available in two versions, one with two and one with four input ports (DP and USB).

https://connectpro.com/product/udp2-12ap-kit-2port-dual-displayport-kvm/

https://connectpro.com/product/udp2-14ap-kit-4-port-usb-dual-displayport-kvm-switch/

Unfortunately they are not available yet. The weird thing is that they have been on the site since about a year now. I wonder if they will ever be available.

Comment: FYI, these are finally available for purchase. I've also been watching them for the last 2 years.

Comment: I've noticed. They only sell in small badges so far though, 1st batch is already sold out

Comment: Four years later and this is still the only KVM with DDM and DisplayPort out there? So far that appears to be the case.

Comment: Few months later, desperately in needs of a full-time EDID, DDM, DisplayPort 2x2 KVM 4k@120 / 2k@144, with an additional trick : Europe. Still no more reference on the market ?